# Run New Class in existing project ECLIPSE

Tags: java, eclipse, run-configuration

I am trying to run a new class(guidemo is class name) which in existing project.
to run it as always if I click on run there is no option for newly created class .if I click run the old class is running.
now what should I do to run the new class, I attached image
[i attached image of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RedpV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run button in eclipse shows the run configurations that you have previously ran.
So simply to add a run configuration for your newly added class just run the class guidemo  as run as --> java application. After this you will be able to see it where you can see other run configs. Pic attached [image]

After doing this you will be able to see the run config here. Pic attached
[image]